# The class "The class "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key" is not persistable

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am trying to delete multiple entities given a List of Keys, I.e.:

```
List keys = obj.getKeys(); pm.deletePersistentAll(keys);
```

However, when I try to delete the entities I get the following exception:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: One or more instances could not be deleted
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.deletePersistentAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:809)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.access$301(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:39)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$2.call(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:112)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$2.call(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:110)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$BatchManagerWrapper.call(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:125)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$BatchManagerWrapper.access$200(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:121)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.deletePersistentAll(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:110)

   NestedThrowablesStackTrace: org.datanucleus.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "The class "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.
at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:241)
```

Has anyone experienced this before? I've made sure my classes are enhanced and that all Class's have been marked as PersistenceCapable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only delete a persistent object (what you pass in to pm.deletePersistentAll). A "Key" is not a persistent object

Comment: Is there not a way to delete an entity by its key? Seems a little strange that I must first load each object only to delete it.

Comment: pm.deletePersistent handles cascade deletion etc too. Just deleting something from the datastore risks leaving orphans and incorrect relations to them, hence why any sane object persistence API won't allow it. You could do Query q = pm.newQuery(...) to select the objects to delete and call q.deletePersistentAll().

Answer (score 0):

To delete an entity by key, try

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
ds.delete(key)
```

Comment: If some other object refers to this (e.g with GAE/J latest storage version the parent holds keys to children) then doing that will leave trailing references.